# How to assign the resulting content from a promise function to a variable?

Tags: typescript, promise

How can I assign the resulting content from a promise function to a variable?

I can see the result of a function in a `var.then` but what I really want to do is assign that result to a variable that I use elsewhere. I want to avoid lots of nested
`get thing a -> .then do thingb -> .then do thing c`

I've created a simple reproduction, but my real case is getting data from the result `fetch`

I have a script that calls a function in a lib (see Simple library at the end of this post) below that returns `Promise<string>`.

I can use the function access the result inside a `.then` by doing

```
const myLib = new MyLib()
const hello = myLib.hello()
hello.then((result) => {
    console.log(`Result : ${result}`)
})
```

What I want to do though is assign the value of this result to a variable for use elsewhere.

`hello` at this point is an `object Promise` when logged.

How do I get the value and assign it to a var?

**Things I've tried and what they result in**

*Return the result from `.then` - returns a Promise*

```
var stringy = hello.then((result) => {
    return result
})

Stringy: [object Promise]
```

*Declare a variable and assign it within `.then` - Undefined output*

```
var stringy
hello.then((result) => {
    stringy = result
})

Stringy: undefined
```

*Use `await`*

```
const hello = await myLib.hello()

Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 
'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext', 
and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.ts(1378)
```

**Simple library**

```
class MyLib {
    public async hello(): Promise<string> {
        return 'Hello World!';
    }
}

export default MyLib
```

Comment: This is an XY problem. You probably should not have a global shared mutable variable. What are you trying to achieve? top-level await may be a solution if you use ES modules as the error is telling you, but there is nothing wrong with having a main function that is async. Your code does not need to be "flat", if stuff happens in the future, then so be it.

Comment: Forgot to mention that Promise.then behaves like Array.flatMap, so you would not be nesting even if the return value of a callback is a Promise itself, it would get flattened automagically.

Comment: You cannot access it elsewhere, *without waiting for the promise*. It's just impossible to get a value that doesn't exist yet from the future. It seems you already know how to wait for promises, use that syntax. "*I want to avoid lots of nested get thing a -> .then do thingb -> .then do thing c*" - using `await` means you don't need to nest. If you have trouble with applying this, please post your real code instead of a toy example.